# C++: Data Types & Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, data-structures, types

I am coding a program that determines the lowest operating cost of 5 named boats. This is calculated using predetermined integers stored in arrays along with user input integers. 
I was able to complete the program, but I want to name each boat and output the lowest operating cost with its corresponding boat name. Any insight is appreciated! Thanks and excuse my sloppy code, I am new at this.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h> 
using namespace std;


   void swap(int *xp, int *yp) 
{ 
    int temp = *xp; 
    *xp = *yp; 
    *yp = temp; 
} 

void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n) 
{ 
   int i, j; 
   for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)       

       for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)  
           if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) 
              swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]); 
} 

void printArray(int arr[], int size) 
{ 
    int i; 
    for (i=0; i < size; i++) 
        printf("%d ", arr[i]); 
        cout<<"\n";
     }


int main()
{

//Declarations

int numBoats = 5;

int boatData[5];

int costGas;

int yearsService;

int i;

int j;

int boatArray[5][3] = {{30, 100, 5000}, 
                     {20, 200, 10000}, 
                     {30, 200, 2000}, 
                     {25, 150, 12000}, 
                     {30, 50, 8000}};

//User input 

cout << "Please enter the first boats cost of gas: "<<endl;
cin >> costGas;
cout << "The cost of gas you entered is " << costGas << endl;

cout << "Please enter the number of years in service: " << endl;
cin >> yearsService;
cout << "The number of years in service you entered is " << yearsService << endl;

//Calculations

for (i = 0; i < numBoats; i++) {

int mpg = boatArray[i][1];
int maintenanceCost = boatArray[i][2]; 
int purchaseCost = boatArray[i][3];

int totalMiles = 15000 * yearsService;
int gasTotal = totalMiles / mpg;
int maintenanceTotal = maintenanceCost * yearsService;
int operatingCost = purchaseCost + gasTotal + maintenanceTotal;

boatData[i] = operatingCost;
}

//Print operating costs

 cout<<"The operating costs of each boat is: "<<endl;

printArray(boatData, numBoats);

//Bubblesort

bubbleSort(boatData, numBoats); 
printArray(boatData, numBoats);

cout<<"Your lowest operating cost is "<<boatData[0]<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello Neo J. Wellcome to SO. Do you know `struct`?

Comment: I am currently investigating for the first time ... any insight would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you try classes? Being it c++, you could have a Class Boat, with several parameters (name, cost, years, etc), and in the main you create 5 objects of Boat, instantiating the parameters, and calling functions of that class!

Comment: "I want to name each boat and output the lowest operating cost with its corresponding boat name" -- OK, what's wrong with what you have?

Comment: Since you are a beginner, let me tell you first that your program find the solution, but not in the best way. You should look **just** for the lowest value and not to sort the array by the value (let me know if you understand this part). But with your appoach is still posible to print the name of the boat. **1)** create an array of names, **2)** create a `swapName` function that you call every time you call `swap` and **3)** add the output of the name at the end of your `cout<<"Your lowest ...`. This makes any sense to you??

Comment: What I have finds the lowest operating cost, but I'd like to provide a name for each boat (ie: Boat1, Boat2,...) so that the final output is not only the lowest operating cost but also its corresponding boat.

Comment: Let me show what I'm talking about with an example

Comment: Also, Neo – now, be *straight* with us – is this ***homework?*** Because, if it is, you really need to be taking your questions to your *instructor,* so that (s)he will be aware of what questions students such as yourself are actually having.  Take it from someone who teaches night classes – "instructors *need* this feeback from students!"  (And, "you need to work very hard to come up with answers yourself, first."  Don't cheat *yourself.* "Give it that old college try.")

Comment: A common C/C++ approach would be to define `boatArray` as an array of `struct`, where each element includes named fields – `mpg, maintenanceCost, purchaseCost,` and ... `boatName`.  We would use this, for clarity, instead of a two-dimensional array, and we would in the process get rid of the issue of having multiple data-types.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I will do to find the lowest operative cost:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h> 
using namespace std;


int NUM_BOATS = 5;

struct Boat {
  int mpg;
  int maintenanceCost;
  int purchaseCost;
  string name;
  int operatingCost; // total of your calculation
};

void caculation(Boat& boat, int yearsService){
  int totalMiles = 15000 * yearsService;
  int gasTotal = totalMiles / boat.mpg;
  int maintenanceTotal = boat.maintenanceCost * yearsService;
  boat.operatingCost = boat.purchaseCost + gasTotal + maintenanceTotal;
}

void print(Boat& boat){
  cout << "mpg: " << boat.mpg << endl;
  cout << "maintenanceCost: " << boat.maintenanceCost << endl;
  cout << "purchaseCost: " << boat.purchaseCost << endl;
  cout << "name: " << boat.name << endl;
  cout << "operatingCost: " << boat.operatingCost << endl;
}

int main()
{
  Boat BoatData[5] = { {30, 100, 5000, "Boat a", 0},
                       {20, 110, 5500, "Boat b", 0},
                       {35, 120, 4000, "Boat c", 0},
                       {10, 300, 1000, "Boat d", 0},
                       {40, 200, 3000, "Boat e", 0},
                      } ;
  //User input 
  int costGas;
  cout << "Please enter the first Boats cost of gas: "<<endl;
  cin >> costGas;
  cout << "The cost of gas you entered is " << costGas << endl;
  int yearsService;
  cout << "Please enter the number of years in service: " << endl;
  cin >> yearsService;
  cout << "The number of years in service you entered is " << yearsService << endl;

  int iMin = 0;
  int minCost = 99000; // a really high number

  for(int i=0; i<NUM_BOATS; ++i){
    print(BoatData[i]);
    caculation(BoatData[i], yearsService);  // calculate all your operatingCost
    if (BoatData[i].operatingCost < minCost){  // and check if is the lowest operatingCost
      iMin = i;      // if it is, save that index
    }
  }

  cout << "Your lowest operating cost is " << BoatData[iMin].operatingCost << " with the boat " << BoatData[iMin].name << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

But based on your code and your comments, your approach is to sort the array, so this is what you sould implement in your code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h> 
using namespace std;


void swap(int *xp, int *yp) 
{ 
    int temp = *xp; 
    *xp = *yp; 
    *yp = temp; 
} 

void swapName(string& x, string& y) 
{ 
    string temp(x); 
    x = y; 
    y = temp; 
} 

void bubbleSort(int arr[], string boatName[], int n) 
{ 
   int i, j; 
   for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)       

       for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)  
           if (arr[j] > arr[j+1])
           { 
              swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]);              // if you have to swap the data
              swapName(boatName[j], boatName[j+1]);  // swap also the names
           }
} 

void printArray(int arr[], int size) 
{ 
    int i; 
    for (i=0; i < size; i++) 
        printf("%d ", arr[i]); 
}


int main()
{
  //Declarations
  int numBoats = 5;
  int boatData[5];
  string boatName[5] = {"a", "gg", "tt", "hh", "jj"};//
  int costGas;
  int i;
  int j;
  int boatArray[5][3] = {{30, 100, 5000}, 
                       {20, 200, 10000}, 
                       {30, 200, 2000}, 
                       {25, 150, 12000}, 
                       {30, 50, 8000}};

  //User input 
  cout << "Please enter the first boats cost of gas: "<<endl;
  cin >> costGas;
  cout << "The cost of gas you entered is " << costGas << endl;
  int yearsService;
  cout << "Please enter the number of years in service: " << endl;
  cin >> yearsService;
  cout << "The number of years in service you entered is " << yearsService << endl;

  //Calculations
  for (i = 0; i < numBoats; i++) {
    int mpg = boatArray[i][1];
    int maintenanceCost = boatArray[i][2]; 
    int purchaseCost = boatArray[i][3];

    int totalMiles = 15000 * yearsService;
    int gasTotal = totalMiles / mpg;
    int maintenanceTotal = maintenanceCost * yearsService;
    int operatingCost = purchaseCost + gasTotal + maintenanceTotal;

    boatData[i] = operatingCost;
  }

  //Print operating costs
   cout<<"The operating costs of each boat is: "<<endl;
  printArray(boatData, numBoats);

  //Bubblesort
  bubbleSort(boatData, boatName, numBoats);  // pass also the name's array
  printArray(boatData, numBoats);

  cout<<"Your lowest operating cost is "<<boatData[0]<< " with the boat " << boatName[0] << endl;  // print the name

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would just add some reference array with unique numbers for boats and sort them together with values. The sort function:

```
void bubbleSort (int id[], int arr[], int n) 
{ 
int i, j; 
for (i = 0;  i < n - 1;  i++)
    for (j = 0;  j < n - i - 1;  j++)  
        if  ( arr[j] > arr[j+1] ) {
            swap ( arr[j], arr[j+1] ); 
            swap ( id[j], id[j+1] ); 
        }
}
```

Then I refer to names by these sorted ID's.
This simplified example shows how it could apply to your case, it prints some data (here names) before and after sorting:

```
int main () 
{

const int n = 5;
int     boatID[n] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
string  name[n] = { "oak", "pine", "maple", "cypress", "elm" };
int     value[n] = { 20, 10, 0, 25, 15 };

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    cout << "id: " << boatID[i] << "  value: " << value[i] << "  name: " << name[boatID[i]] << endl;

bubbleSort (boatID, value, n);  // sort references by value

cout << "* sorted *" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    cout << "id: " << boatID[i]  << "  value: " << value[i] << "  name: " << name[boatID[i]] << endl;

}
```

Note that `boatID[i]` is used instead of the index `name[]` output.